# ui-select first item disappears

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

**Example plunk here**: https://plnkr.co/edit/guzu730yVTramDk7l4ue?p=preview

I'm using angular ui-select and the problem is when I select the first element from the list, it disappears.

select in my html:

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="bootstrap" search-enabled="false">
    <ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people">
        <span ng-bind-html="person.name"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $http){
   $scope.people=[
      { id: 1, name: "First" }, 
      { id: 1, name: "Second"}, 
      { id: 1, name: "Third"}
   ];
   $scope.person = {};
   $scope.person.selected = $scope.people[0];
});
```

In this example:

1. The select element has "First" person selected.
2. I select "Second" from the dropdown.
3. I want to choose "First" again but it's not visible anymore.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what the code should do?

Comment: In example you can see when you select "First" from the list, it disappears and you cannot choose that person again. It should stay on the select and still be selectable after it is changed but it's not.

Comment: There is an issue on github https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/1653

Comment: @Yuri Thanks. Fixed it by changing `<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="bootstrap" search-enabled="false">` to  `<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="bootstrap" search-enabled="false" remove-selected="false">`